# Why is my Facebook like button causing comment box to flash and disappear on my Joomla website?

Tags: joomla, facebook-like, confirm

I am using Joomla 3.1.1 on my website. I have tried several extensions to try to incorporate a Facebook like button and the result is always the same: a comment box flashes for a moment and then the word "confirm" replaces "like". There must be an underlying issue with my website as this happens with all extensions, yet only with the Facebook 'like' function. All other shares seem to be working fine.

My website is offline but I have put it online momentarily to see if that changed anything.. it didn't.

Can someone point me in the right direction to solve this issue? Am I out of my league trying to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this happens when a site is new and you click like too many times. There was also a problem with the comment box that was fixed by going to root/media/jui/css/bootstrap-extended.css and changing

```
iframe,
svg {
max-width: 100%;
}
```

to

```
iframe,
svg {
max-width: inherited;
}
```

Hope this helps someone.